# Hide menu element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide  class element `media-caption` and make it visible only when one hover over it and first element of the submenu needs to be visible when one hover over the parent menu also.

I tried to fix it using jquery but i so far it is not working in a right way.

Please have a look at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPWDm/26/)  | [fiddle demo view](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wPWDm/26/show/#)

I also not able to understand why image changes automatically and not the `media-caption` elements.

Thanks.

Please feel free to make changes to make it look more professional as i am just a beginner.

Comment: I tried to make it work using css but it didnt work so switched to jquery. if i add background color rather than transparent image then it works fine but i need to make it work on transparency..

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava How would you hover over an element having `display: none`?

Comment: My bad it will like `class-name >second-class-name{display:none}` and `class-name:hover>second-class-name{display:block}`

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava, can you fix it on fiddle please....

Comment: i had something similar before `.nav ul li a:hover  .dropdown ul li p:first-child 
{
 display:block;
}`

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava, Didn't get you if you fixed it then it is not working as it still overlaps text ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most optimized sample, but it's working.

I use jquery for this, so, i removed every hover statment for submenu in CSS.

Then i add the hover/out effect with jquery :

```
$(".dropdown ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).parent().find( ".active" ).css( "display", "none" );
            $(this).find( ".dd-panel" ).css( "display", "block" );

     });
});

 $(".dropdown ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).find( ".dd-panel" ).css( "display", "none" );
            $(this).parent().find( ".active" ).css( "display", "block" );
     });

});
```

And i add a flag too in order to identify the first element that must be displayed if not hovered:

```
$(".dropdown li:first-child .dd-panel",$(this)).css( "display", "block" );
$(".dropdown li:first-child .dd-panel",$(this)).addClass("active");
```

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5eecT/)

Ask if you have some troubles using this.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of jquery. Remove the jquery first.. and your code works fine.

if you don't want to display the first sub items image then just remove the following code

```
.dropdown li:first-child .dd-panel
```

from your css file

Comment: I do want to display image and text. but i want it to be visible on hover effect of that element only and first submenu element & relevant text to be visible when one hover over it parent menu `li`

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sarathsprakash/efBc5/1/)

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".nav>li").on("mouseenter", function () {
        if($(this).find('.dd-panel').length>0)
        {
       $(this).find('.dropdown').addClass("has-panel");
        }
        $(this).find(".media-caption:first").css("display", "block");

    });

    $(".nav>li").find(".dropdown li:not(li:first)").on("mouseenter", function () {

        $(this).parents('.nav>li').find('.media-caption:first').css("display", "none");
    });


});
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, sorry for the delay , that is fixed, I have updated the demo and the code

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker please see the fiddle